# How to jump to function call?

Tags: ctags

After generating a tags file with `exuberant-ctags` I can jump from a function call to its declaration with `<C-]>` which is pretty convenient.

My question is how to do it in the other way? When my cursor is on the definition of a function, how can I go to the lines where the function is called?

When I look to the file generated by ctags I only see informations related to the location of the definition and not of the calls, does it means that I can't do that, that Vim as a clever workaround or that I need to use something else than `exuberant-ctags`?

Comment: Ack or Ag will also work and you can find plugin wrappers for these command line tools pretty easily. E.g. https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim and https://github.com/rking/ag.vim

Answer (score 15):

You can't jump to function calls with `ctags`.  For C/C++ and Java there is [`cscope`](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/), and it integrates nicely with Vim (see [`:help cscope`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_cscop.txt.html)).  For other languages you might be able to find a tool that generates / exports `cscope`-compatible databases (f.i. [`hscope`](https://github.com/bosu/hscope) for Haskell, and [`starscope`](https://github.com/eapache/starscope/) for Ruby, Go, and JavaScript).  You can also use `cscope` with [GNU global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) databases, by pointing `cscopeprg` to `gtags-cscope`.

On a side note: if you aren't put off by occasionally puzzling use of [Engrish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engrish), ;) you probably also want to use [universal-ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) instead of `exuberant-ctags`.  The latter hasn't been updated in years.  The former is an actively maintained fork.

Comment: Does cscope support other languages than C/C++ and Java ?

Comment: @edi9999 `cscope` itself supports C/C++, Lex, and Yacc.  The support for Java is marginally useful.  You can get support for (old-style) PHP and JavaScript from GNU `global`, via the `gtags-cscope` utility.  And, as I said above, there are other indexers that can export `cscope`-compatible databases.

Answer (score 9):

You can't do that with ctags.

Try a beefier alternative like [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) (which even has its own help section: `:help cscope`) or [global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/).

Comment: Does cscope support other languages than C/C++ and Java ?

Comment: Yes, at least PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: @romainl Nope, `cscope` itself supports neither PHP, nor JavaScript.  You can however index PHP and JavaScript files with GNU `global`, then run `gtags-cscope` to use the resulting `gtags` file with `cscope`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, yes, cscope [supports JavaScript](http://imgur.com/ndwAK4q) (and CSS, appparently).

Comment: and [PHP](http://imgur.com/GLqQ5vp) too.

Comment: @romainl You should consider looking at `cscope`'s [sources](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=4664) instead of speculating based on quick experiments.  `cscope` has a rather relaxed C parser.  That's all it has, and all it does.  With that parser it "supports" a lot of languages, for suitable values of "support".  Constructs are recognized as long as they look more or less like C.  Which is why f.i. Java classes and newer PHP constructs are not recognized.  Compare f.i. with [starscope](https://github.com/eapache/starscope/), which actually allows adding new languages.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, I wouldn't call daily usage "quick experiment". Whether support for JavaScript is intended or not doesn't really matter: cscope works with JavaScript and that's all that matters to the end user.

Answer (score 9):

You could use Vim's **grep** command to search all the files in your project:

```
:grep! "\<<cword>\>" . -r
:copen
```

Let's put that in a keybind:

```
nnoremap <F4> :grep! "\<<cword>\>" . -r<CR>:copen<CR>
```

I find this one-key project-wide search invaluable when I am exploring a large unfamiliar codebase.

`\<` and `\>` are regexp sequences which indicate the start and end of a word, so you won't get partial matches.  (The `-w` option to grep might be another way to achieve this.)

However, this is an **unintelligent search**, so it can produce false-positives if the same word appears in unrelated contexts.

---

Truthfully, I use my own [modified version of the grep.vim plugin](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/grep.vim) instead. This is slightly friendlier to use:

- It lets you edit the search pattern, and also the grep commandline (so you can target specific folders like `src/ lib/` instead of `.`) and remembers the changes.
- I added support for Google's [**csearch**](https://github.com/google/codesearch).  This can be much faster than grep (on HDDs) because it builds an index of words rather than scanning each file every time.  Notably, csearch uses a slightly different regexp standard, so `\b` must be used instead of `\<` and `\>`.

I configure it and exclude some standard files [like this](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/5e67249194407360d12f38e7f5b2f085937fd286/.vimrc#L147-L170).

For fast access, I create [two keybinds](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/5e67249194407360d12f38e7f5b2f085937fd286/.vim/plugin/joeykeymap.vim#L557-L592).  <kbd>F3</kbd> lets me edit the commandline, <kbd>F4</kbd> uses the previously configured commandline without any extra keystrokes.  The mechanism is pretty ugly, and could use some cleanup, but it has served me well.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add your own search patterns on the command line or in the config:

```
--regex-c++='/(\.|->)([[:alnum:]_]+)[[:space:]]*\(/\2(/i,function instance or call/'
```

This creates a new tag "kind" with the code 'i' (for Instance or Invocation) to distinguish it from other tags. It also creates the tags with a trailing '(', because when you are looking for the definition, having 100 invocation results can muddy the waters. So searching for 'my_func(' limits the results in either case. If you don't like that, you can just remove the `(` after the `\2`.

You can use this options multiple times for the same kind. So, instead of trying to come up with a single regex that will match all calls, you can have several, simpler ones that capture different kinds of calls.

This isn't foolproof, and with the patterns I've built up, I still get non-call results, but it's definitely better than nothing! :)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

I always use two tools together: Exuberant Ctags, same as you, plus [GNU ID Utils](https://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/).  This project provides the `mkid` utility to build an `ID` database for fast querying with `lid`.

The Vim-side setup is this line in `.vimrc`:

```
:set grepprg=lid\ --word\ --result=grep\ '$*'\ \\\|\ sort\ -n\ -t\ :\ -k\ 2
```

The sorting step is in there because `lid` has a way of putting out matches in a funny order that jumps around in a file rather than being ordered by line number.

I make two more definitions in connections with this:

```
:nmap K "_y:execute count ? ( ":!man " . count . " " . expand("<cword>") ) : ( ":grep \\<" . expand("<cword>") . "\\>")^M
:vmap K "zy:execute ":grep " . getreg("z")^M
```

This gives me a <kbd>K</kbd> shortcut for searching for occurrences of identifiers using `:grep`.

The `:nmap K` provides dispatch for searching for the identifier under the cursor. Because `K` is an existing command for invoking `man` (with an optional numeric prefix to specify the `man` section number), I partially preserve the behavior: if a numeric prefix is given, `K` still does the `man` lookup. Without a prefix it does `:grep`.

The `:vmap K` is for searching for text that has been visually selected.